# SQL subquery confusion: how to refer to outer query column in the SAME table

Tags: sql, join, subquery, business-objects

I'm fairly new to SQL. I'm trying to construct a certain query in Business Objects by manually tweaking the SQL. I have a beginner's understanding of subqueries, however there is one particular problem that eludes me. I'll try to explain using an example of code:

```
SELECT
TBL1.ID
TBL1.Field1text
TBL1.Field2date
CASE WHEN
    (
    TBL1.Field1text = 'ValueTwo'
    AND
    TBL1.Field2date >= '30/11/2014'
    /* Arbitrary date. I actually want this to be, for example,
        "TBL1.Field2date minus 2 months where TBL1.ID is the same, and
        TBL1.Field1text is ValueOne" */
    )
THEN 'Match'
ELSE 'No Match'
END
As CutomColumnNameToShowMatches
WHERE
TBL1.Field1text = 'ValueOne'
AND
TBL1.Field2date BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '31/12/2015'
```

So as you can see, I'm using a CASE WHEN clause in the selection criteria to return a custom field which shows whether there's a match or not (explained below).

The source table has a bunch of records where each value of Field1text is associated with a particular date (Field2date). The "ID" field is not a primary key. The same ID may be used across multiple records. For example, ID 52 may have several records, all showing different values of Field1text and their associated Field2date. With me so far? Good.

My basic query returns a list of records where Field1text is "ValueOne". This is easy enough. However, what I then want to do is determine - for each of those records:

***"Take the ID number. Search the table, and find whether that same ID ALSO has any records where Field1text equals ValueTwo, and where the Field2date of that ValueTwo record is within 2 months of the Field2date of the ValueOne record". If yes then return Match. If not, return no match.***

Does that all make sense? Please ask me to clarify if needed.

My research so far has suggested that some sort of JOIN might be the answer: however I am not sure how that would apply in this situation, or even if it would be the right approach.

The code above works well enough, but only with a specified date in the subquery. I need a way to make that date variable, and linked to the date from the ValueOne record of the same ID.

Please note that we're working all from the same table here. Additionally, as I'm working in Business Objects, I have no capacity to create and save a named query like one might do in MS Access. Everything has to work from one piece of SQL code.

Grateful for any assistance! :)

Comment: A `FROM` clause would help.

Comment: Knowing what the actual PK is would also help.

Comment: Also: Do you actually mean "within two months" or do you mean "within 60 days"? The semantics are very different, as Dec. 31 ***is*** within two months of Oct. 1, although being 91 days later.

Comment: Oops - yes, I forgot the FROM clause in my re-typed example :) It's not important to the question though: just assume FROM TBL1.
And yes, I'm aware 2 months isn't the same as 60 days - but it was just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign different alias names to the same table and join the two aliases together.  Using your example, I created a query that only shows rows that HAVE matches within the timeframe. It uses alias names 'a' and 'b' as follows:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.Field1text,
    a.Field2date
FROM
    TBL1 AS a
    INNER JOIN TBL1 AS b ON 
        a.ID = b.ID 
        AND a.Field1text = b.Field1text
        AND b.Field2date > a.Field2date 
        AND b.Field2date <= DATEADD(month, 2, a.Field2date )
```

Alternatively, if you want all rows from 'a' and just an indicator if a match was found in 'b' then try this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.Field1text,
    a.Field2date,
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 
                    CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 'No Match' ELSE 'Match' END
                FROM 
                    TBL1 AS b
                WHERE
                    a.ID = b.ID 
                    AND a.Field1text = b.Field1text
                    AND b.Field2date > a.Field2date 
                    AND b.Field2date <= DATEADD(month, 2, a.Field2date )
            ) IS NULL 
        THEN 'No Match' 
        ELSE 'Match' 
    END AS [MatchSearch]
FROM
    TBL1 AS a
WHERE
    a.Field1text = 'ValueOne'
    AND a.Field2date BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
```

NOTE: This will still show the rows from 'b' that matched the outer WHERE clause.  If you do not want to show them, then consider adding a GROUP BY clause.

PS: I couldn't find the FROM section of your query, so I made one up.
Also, your date range text is not formatted properly: '31/12/2015'

Comment: Don - looks like you're onto something there. I didn't know one could assign aliases to tables at SQL runtime (told you I was a n00b at it). I'll try this tomorrow and let you know if it works - thanks!

Comment: Don, it works! Thank you so much.
I had to slightly modify your example, but the principle of assigning an alias to a table was great.
Btw - my date is formatted correctly internationally. I am not American! Unfortunately many American servers switch round the dates though, so I tend to use 31-dec-2015 to ensure that can't happen :)

Comment: Awesome,  Sorry about the date mixup, my server threw errors. I'm glad it worked for you.